# Disqus plugin outputs script as literal text

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes, disqus

After installing the Disqus plugin, their JavaScript code started popping up as plain text on my site in several places. My hypothesis is that it pops up at the end of any loop involving `the_post()`. This is one of them.

[image: Screenshot of the glitch]

Here's a snippet from my `front-page.php`:

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'skill' => $term->slug,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'pf_startyear',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    ));
?>
    <div class="box">
        <h4 class="boxTitle"><?= $term->name ?></h4>
        <div class="boxFrontContent table tblvtop">
            <div>
<?php
    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
                <div class="contentItem">
                    <a href="<?= get_term_link($term->slug, "skill") . "#" . $post->post_name ?>"><img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, "pf_img", true)) ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" class="pfItem" /></a>
                    <p><?= get_post_meta($post->ID, "pf_pitch", true) ?></p>
                </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is how it renders:

[image: Output tree]

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this script from breaking my site layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some themes the Disqus code is rendered at a bad position within the loop. Go to the Disqus plugin within Wordpress, click the "Advanced options" tab, and then check "Output javascript in footer". That should fix this.